# Refer to variable by part of the variable name

Tags: r

It seems that, in R, I can refer to a variable with part of a variable name. But I am confused about why I can do that.

Use the following code as an example:

```
library(car)
scatterplot(housing ~ total)
house.lm <- lm(housing ~ total)
summary(house.lm)
str(summary(house.lm))
summary(house.lm)$coefficients[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coe[2,2]
```

When I print the structure of summary(house.lm), I got the following output:

```
> str(summary(house.lm))
List of 11
 $ call         : language lm(formula = housing ~ total)
 $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language housing ~ total
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(housing, total)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "housing" "total"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "total"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "total"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(housing, total)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "housing" "total"
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:162] -8.96 -11.43 3.08 8.45 2.2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:162] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ coefficients : num [1:2, 1:4] 28.4523 0.0488 10.2117 0.0103 2.7862 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "total"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "t value" "Pr(>|t|)"
 $ aliased      : Named logi [1:2] FALSE FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "total"
 $ sigma        : num 53.8
 $ df           : int [1:3] 2 160 2
 $ r.squared    : num 0.123
 $ adj.r.squared: num 0.118
 $ fstatistic   : Named num [1:3] 22.5 1 160
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "value" "numdf" "dendf"
 $ cov.unscaled : num [1:2, 1:2] 3.61e-02 -3.31e-05 -3.31e-05 3.67e-08
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "total"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "total"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "summary.lm"
```

However, it seems that I can refer to the variable coefficients with all of the following commands:

```
summary(house.lm)$coe[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coef[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coeff[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coeffi[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coeffic[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coeffici[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coefficie[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coefficien[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coefficient[2,2]
summary(house.lm)$coefficients[2,2]
```

They all give the same results: 0.01029709

Therefore, I was wondering when I can refer to a variable with only part of its name in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping

> When calling a function you can specify arguments by position, by
>   complete name, or by partial name. Arguments are matched first by
>   exact name (perfect matching), then by prefix matching, and finally by
>   position.

When you are doing quick coding to analyse some data, using partial names is not a problem, but I tend to agree, it's not good when writing code. In a package you can't do that, `R-CMD check` will find every occurence.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it when rest of name is unambiguous. For example

```
df <- data.frame(abcd = c(1,2,3), xyz = c(4,5,6), abc = c(5,6,7))
> df$xy
[1] 4 5 6
> df$ab
NULL
> df$x
[1] 4 5 6
```

`df$xy` and even `df$x` gives right data, but `df$ab` results in `NULL` because it can refer to both `df$abc` and `df$abcd`. It's like when you type `df$xy` in RStudio and press *Ctrl + Space* you will get rigtht variable name, so you could refer to part of variable name.